# MVC 5 Application using Jquery ajax. How to use data annotation when pass selection ID as -1?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

My front end Jquery script like this.

```
//Json String

JSON.stringify({
    Id: CurrentID,
    CustomerId: $.trim($("#CustomerList").val()),
    StoreId: $.trim($("#StoreList").val()),
    ProductId: $.trim($("#ProductList").val()),
    Date: $.trim($("txtDate").val()),
})
```

this will send customerId as -1 when user has not selected any.

My back end validation is

```
 public JsonResult Create(BLL.Model.SalesDTO sales)
{
    try
    {                
        var valid = TryUpdateModel(sales);
        if (valid)
        {
            var data = Operation.AddSale(sales);
            //return RedirectToAction("Index");
            //Index();
            //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return Json(new
        {
            Valid = valid,
            Errors = GetErrorsFromModelState(),
            //StudentsPartial = studentPartialViewHtml
        });
    }
    catch
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            Valid = false,
            Errors = GetErrorsFromModelState(),
            //StudentsPartial = studentPartialViewHtml
        });
    }
}
```

Data annotation class

```
public class SalesDTO
{        
    [Required (ErrorMessage ="Customer field required" ) ]
    public int CustomerId {get; set;}
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Store field required")]
    public int StoreId{ get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product field required")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required , DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

But when it passes -1 as customerID it doesn't give any error and accept -1.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use the `Range` attribute. Please also note that `Required` attribute on non-nullable types is useless. It should be used only on nullable or reference types. If you want to make sure that the client sends those fields change your data type from `int` to `int?` (same for `DateTime?`).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `[Range]` data annotation:

```
 [Range(0, int.MaxValue)]
 [Required (ErrorMessage ="Customer field required" ) ]
 public int CustomerId {get; set;}
```